# Having trouble converting HTML to PDF using jspdf

Tags: html, jspdf

I am a teacher working on a project that I've started last summer.  I am now trying to convert a form that I've created in HTML to a PDF.  Eventually I would like for this PDF to be stored in a mySQL database and printed to a designated printer on our network.

The problem I'm having is that nothing is happening. The page is not being changed into a PDF. I've looked at several examples of this process and The code doesn't seem to be doing anything.

Here is my HTML containing the form

--------------------------Begin HTML--------------------------------------

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<?php
    $img_1 = 'new_checkbox_empty.gif';
?>
<head>
<title>OUSD URF</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="urfForm">
<center>
<table border="1" width="100%">
    <table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td><IMG SRC="OUSD_URF_Logo.jpg"></td>
        <td>Universal Office Discipline Referral Form</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td>Student________________________</td>
        <td>Grade______</td>
        <td>Referring Staff___________________________</td>
        <td>Date_________</td>
        <td>Time_________</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <HR width="100%">
    <table border="1" width="100%">
    <thead>Pre-referral Interventions (For Minor Behaviors). Before making an office Referral, please complete at least 3 pre-referral interventions.<br>Minor Behaviors may include: Disrespect/non-compliance, Dress code Violation, Electronic Device, Horseplay, Inappropriate language, Inappropriate physical contact, Misuse/destruction of property, Tardy</thead>
    <tr>
        <td width="33%"><IMG SRC="<?php echo $img_1?>" style="margin: 0px 5px" style="margin: 0px 5px">5-1 Positive Reinforcement</td>
        <td width="33%"><IMG SRC="new_checkbox_empty.gif" style="margin: 0px 5px" style="margin: 0px 5px">Parent Consultation</td>
        <td width="33%"><IMG SRC="new_checkbox_empty.gif" style="margin: 0px 5px" style="margin: 0px 5px">Restorative Conversation</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><IMG SRC="new_checkbox_empty.gif" style="margin: 0px 5px">Buddy Room (15 Minutes Max)</td>
        <td><IMG SRC="new_checkbox_empty.gif" style="margin: 0px 5px">Problem Solving Conference</td>
        <td><IMG SRC="new_checkbox_empty.gif" style="margin: 0px 5px">Reviewed IEP/504</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><IMG SRC="new_checkbox_empty.gif" style="margin: 0px 5px">Behavior Contract</td>
        <td><IMG SRC="new_checkbox_empty.gif" style="margin: 0px 5px">Prompting Desired Behavior</td>
        <td><IMG SRC="new_checkbox_empty.gif" style="margin: 0px 5px">Re-teaching Desired Behavior</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><IMG SRC="new_checkbox_empty.gif" style="margin: 0px 5px">Conflict Mediation</td>
        <td><IMG SRC="new_checkbox_empty.gif" style="margin: 0px 5px">Proximity or Seat change</td>
        <td><IMG SRC="new_checkbox_empty.gif" style="margin: 0px 5px">Reviewed IEP/504</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><IMG SRC="new_checkbox_empty.gif" style="margin: 0px 5px">Explicitly taught & Rehearsed Rules & Expectations</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</table>
</center>
</div>
<br><br>


<a href="javascript:urf2PDF()">Submit Form</a>
<hr />

<script src="jsPDF/jspdf.js"></script>
<script src="jsPDF/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jsPDF/test.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

-------------------------End HTML----------------------------------------

And Here is my js

-----------------------------Begin JS------------------------------------

```
 function urf2PDF() {
var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');
source = $('#urfForm') [0];
var specialElementHandlers = {
    '#bypassme': function(element, renderer){
        return true
    }
};

margins = {
    top: 40,
    left: 50,
    width: 545
};

pdf.fromHTML(
    source
    , margins.left
    , margins.top
    , {
        'width" : margins.width
        , 'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
    },
    function (dispose) {
        pdf.save('urfForm.pdf');
    }
)
}
```

-------------------------End JS-----------------------------------------

Thanks in advance of your assistance.

-Kenny

Comment: Can you please make an edit to describe the problem?

Comment: Nothing is happening.  There is no file created.  No screen is opened to indicate that a PDF has been created.

Comment: I took a look at what you provided. Ozan shows there is a typo there, definitely fix that. Aside from that you need to include 'plugins/from_html.js' to be able to call 'doc.fromHTML()'. There is an undefined pdf error you will keep getting until you include that.
----  'from_html.js:537 Uncaught TypeError: renderer.pdf.sHashCode is not a function' -- this is the next issue I came across. I recommend you implement the 1st 2 fixes and possibly update your libraries. this issue may have been resolved in newer versions of pdfJS. good luck!

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with your ' mark in pdf.fromHTML function. You wrote ' instead of " which broke down the sequence. I've corrected the error below;

```js
function urf2PDF() {
var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');
source = $('#urfForm') [0];
var specialElementHandlers = {
    '#bypassme': function(element, renderer){
        return true
    }
};

margins = {
    top: 40,
    left: 50,
    width: 545
};

pdf.fromHTML(
    source
    , margins.left
    , margins.top
    , {
        "width" : margins.width, 
        "elementHandlers": specialElementHandlers
    },
    function (dispose) {
        pdf.save('urfForm.pdf');
    })
}
```

Can you try and let us know?

Cheers

Comment: I tried the corrections you made and still nothing is happening. I also tried basic tutorials line by line and nothing is working. I tried it with both safari and chrome. Figure if it doesn't work on these, there's no point in trying Firefox.  I also noticed that recent documentation has different variables. Instead of 'doc.text' it has 'jsPDF.text'. It's frustrating to copy and paste code and it still not work. Still interested in learning and I appreciate your responses!!!!